# click event on dynamic li elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Updated the question as per @Jonathan Kuhn's feedback and it works like a charm

I am building a messaging system for my web application.

where the users should be able to communicate with me via messages (ajax)

I am being able to append `<ul>` with additional `<li>` from jQuery

```
$('#send').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var reply = $('#reply').val();

            var project_id = 44; // just for reference
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>messages/send",
                data:{ msg:reply, project_id:project_id },
                success: function (response) {


                    if(response=="success"){

                        $(".messages").append('<li class="message" id="message">'+reply+'<a id="delete">delete</a></li>');
                        var clearText = "ture";

                    }else{

                    }

                }


            });
```

Which is working perfectly fine. But I am having problem while deleting the dynamically added list element.

I tried `bind()` and `on()` jQuery functions but  as I am not much good at it, I am facing a lot of issues.

```
$("#messages").on('click', '#delete', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var id = 22 ; // just for reference
                $.post( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>messages/delete", { type:'single', id:id } )
                  .done(function( data ) {


                });
                $(this).closest('li').remove();
            });
```

My HTML structure is as below

```
<ul class="messages" id="messages">
        <li class="message" id="message">sdaghds<a id="delete">delete</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You have `id="#messages"` on the `<ul>`. Remove the `#` and then the `.on` one should work. Also, ids are supposed to be unique throughout the page. So you shouldn't have multiple `message` ids throughout. If you need multiple, use classes. Remove the id from the `<li>`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I have been developing websites for years now, and I dont believe that these simple errors can consume hours.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is there anyway to close or delete the question ??

Comment: Gotcha. I thought you were saying that this was not the issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `id="#messages"` on the `<ul>`. Remove the `#` and then the `.on` one should work.

Also, ids are supposed to be unique throughout the page. So you shouldn't have multiple `message` ids throughout. If you need multiple, use classes. Remove the id from the `<li>`.